# Issue using gson with Android in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gson

when adding gson 1.4 to the java build path of my Android project I get the error shown below.

Anybody can help?

thanks

```
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable] 
 UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/gson/annotations/Expose;
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:143)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:299)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:276)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$100(Main.java:56)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:228)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:245)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:183)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:139)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.DexWrapper.run(Unknown Source)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.ApkBuilder.executeDx(Unknown Source)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.ApkBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:627)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:170)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:201)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:253)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:256)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:309)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:341)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:140)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:238)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable] 1 error; aborting
 [2010-05-03 18:42:07 - Atable] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Comment: When you mean add to build path do you mean "add external jar" or "add jar"?  I always use "add external jar".

Comment: I cleaned the project and use "add external jar", and it now works... thanks

Comment: Does it then make sense to either post an answer and accept it, or just delete this question?

Answer (score 2):

If someone else is looking after another possible fix:
If you're using Eclipse you have to get sure that the lib-folder is not(!) declared as a src-folder. Instead it only has to be a data-folder from which you can automatically import the lib via context-menu "Add to Build-Path".